# How to display contents of a JSON file on separate UITableviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have this JSON file (the parsing OK, the problem is displaying the contents as I'll describe here) that I need to display in separate UITableViews:

```
{
   "Programs": [

      {"link1": "http://www.myWebSite1.aspx",
       "program name": "Live Show at 9",
       "speaker": "Dr. Speaker 1"
       "day1": "Sunday"
       "day2": "Monday"
       "day3": "Tuesday"},

      {"link2": "http://www.myWebSite2.aspx",
       "name": "Dr. Speaker 2",
       "speaker": "Live Show at 10"
       "day1": "Sunday"
       "day2": "Monday"
       "day3": "Tuesday"
       "day4": "Wednesday"}
   ]
}
```

The user will make his first choice based on the **program/speaker**, then a second UITableView should pop-up presenting the days of the week for him to choose from. So, this second UITableView will display the contents of **day1, day2, day3**, etc...

How can I make such a subdivision, with the contents of this JSON file? Thank you!

Comment: So, what is an actual problem? You don't know how to parse JSON or don't know how to build a table?

Comment: The JSON parsing is OK. The problem is to display the contents in a two steps process, based on the user's decision.

Comment: do you mean that you want to feed the table with the link1 data or with the link2 data depending on the user input?

Comment: The first table would have all programs and speakers displayed. Depending on the choice the second table would show the days of the week. Then a final table is the audio player itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `jsonArray` of `NSDictionary` in new `UITableView` Controller class and then synthesize it. Fill up that array and new `UITableView` pass this array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. For more details go through the link (for just idea)

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2010/06/uitableviewcell-tableviewuitableview.html